# Url rewriting faliure in case of UTF8 urls in nginx

Tags: webserver, url, nginx, rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using Nginx webserver and I want to rewrite some old urls on my site to new ones inorder to prevent 404 errors. For English urls everything is OK and adding a rewrite rule like the following to the server block works fine.

**rewrite ^/omid/$ /omidreza;**

But when it comes to urls containing non-English characters the rule doesn`t work. Has anyone experienced the same issue? How can I fix the problem?

Comment: For persian/arabic links always use a numeric ID with your description, load the page based on ID Number and keep the description for better SEO, just like tabnak website. that way you won't have any problem in these situations, as for your question you better ask it on stackoverflow.com which is better for this kind of questions, i always use ID numbers to don't ever face with this kind of problems